# irregular shaped gradiant contour in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, real-time, gradient

I am looking for a way to get a similar effect as posted [in the Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2113091)

The current solution is very brute force using about 60 intermediate shapes gradually going from the outer shape towards the inner shape while slightly changing the color each time.

Here is their end result :

[image: an example]

This brute force solution consumes way too much cpu power for real-time use.

Is there a "standard" way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

In my particular problem, I only wanted to have a shape fade into the color of the background so my solution was to draw the image slightly larger than usual and use Flash's blur filter to create the gradient effect.  This is suitable only because my background image is a solid color so this won't work for everybody.  This is also a very cpu intensive method but is faster than drawing 60 shapes.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get a somewhat similar effect by applying the GlowFilter to a yellow shape (which would in this case the biggger outer shape), using a blue glow and setting it to "inner glow". You could additionally try to put the inner shape on top of it, also with a yellow fill this time appling a regular outer glow in yellow.

An alternative approach would be to use a Bezier Patch as for example Away3D has it, but ignore the 3D stuff and just use it as a 2D "rubber mat". This will require some experimentation with the right texture to use (I'd start with a radial blue-yellow gradient). Then distort the patch so it fits the shape and then either use that directly or mask it with the original shape.